# javascript regex match the string excluding ending pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone please help me with this:

I'm stuck with JS regular expression.

I have a string like:

> > idont**test**33lkjrhguegh8438934hihfer**TEST2**oidchschds

I want to match everything between `test` and `TEST2` excluding `TEST2`.

So the expected output would be:

> > **test**33lkjrhguegh8438934hihfer

I've tried the following with no success :( :

```
(test)(.*)(?:(?!(TEST2)))
(test)(.*)(?:(TEST2))
(test)(.*)(?:(?!TEST2))
(test)(.*)(?:TEST2)
(test)(.*)(TEST2) //almost works but selects TEST2 also
```

Comment: Just one clarification is necessary: do you want to match the closest window or not? What is the expected output for `xxxtestyyytestzzzTEST2n`? Is it `testzzz` or `testyyytestzzz`?

Comment: @stribizhev it should be `testyyytestzzz` . Thanks!

Comment: Then, the current suggestion below is what you need. Unless you need to match strings with newline symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
/(test.+?)TEST2/
```

and use captured group #1 or using a *positive lookahead*:

```
/test.+?(?=TEST2)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hC4aK7/2)

Comment: `?!` is negative lookahead that means match previous text if it is not followed by ``TEST2`